# WM_GETMINMAXINFO allows minimum to be adjusted larger but not smaller than when resizing started

Tags: winapi, windows-shell

I want to limit the resize range of a windows width based on the height.   I do this via `WM_GETMINMAXINFO`, but there is a quirk (at least in Win10).  If at the time of starting the resize and my window height supports a minimum width of say 80, it never goes below 80.  As I am dragging if I reduce the height so that it changes the minimum width to be 100, it honors that, but if I dragged and increased the height so the minimum width changes to 60, it still stops at 80 (the `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` is being called all along the way).    Is there a trick to get it to work?

One trick I thought of is if I could detect the start of the resize, i could just use some minimum of something like 10, but then the next requests would use the actual real values and would solve the issue. Any thoughts?

TIA!!

Comment: You have no control over when `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` is sent; it's up to the OS when it wants to send a query and whether it caches the results or not. If you want to lock sizing of your window to certain aspect ratios (which is what it sounds like) then I suggest you handle `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`; this lets you make changes to your window size while it is being resized.

Comment: Moved the logic from WM_GETMINMAXINFO over to WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING and now works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the logic to WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING instead of using WM_GETMINMAXINFO.

```
case WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING:
{
  // call default handler
  ::DefWindowProc(hwnd, umsg, wparam, lparam);

  // get structure pointer
  WINDOWPOS *wp=(WINDOWPOS *) lparam;

  // ... add logic here ...

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please feel free to mark yourself to help people with the same issue.